# DocX with filestream doesn't save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, filestream, docx

So for a project I am creating Résumé's and i need to save them into a docx file.
It is a ASP.NET MVC application and for the docx generating I'm using the libray [docx](http://docx.codeplex.com/) to create the document.

I can create the file but the filestream doesn't add the content i put into it.

Here is a the code i use

```
public ActionResult CVToWord(int id) 
        {
            var CV = CVDAO.CV.Single(cv => cv.id == id);
            var filename = "CV - " + CV.firstname + " " + CV.name + " - " + CV.creationdate.ToString("dd MM yyyy") + ".docx";
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            using (DocX doc = DocX.Create(stream)) 
            {
                Paragraph title = doc.InsertParagraph();
                title.Append(CV.firstname + " " + CV.name);
                doc.Save();
            }

            return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", filename);
        }
```

Like i said, this creates the file but the file doesn't have any content. Any one have a idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CVToWord(int id) 
        {
            var CV = CVDAO.CV.Single(cv => cv.id == id);
            var filename = "CV - " + CV.firstname + " " + CV.name + " - " + CV.creationdate.ToString("dd MM yyyy") + ".docx";

            using (DocX doc = DocX.Create(filename)) 
            {
                Paragraph title = doc.InsertParagraph();
                title.Append(CV.firstname + " " + CV.name);
                doc.Save();
            }

            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", filename);
        }
```

This works

Comment: Does this really work as it is? To me it gives error in line "doc.Save();" in IIS it says: Access denied to path...

Comment: @Nmaster88 Your IIS applicationpool user should have permissions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close your FileStream:

```
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Nope, i get a ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.

Comment: Ok, try putting 'using' before your FileStream like you have with your DocX, then all the open handles should be closed for you when it is finished.

Comment: Get the same result. Cannot acces a clossed file, but thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a custom ActionResult for this:

```
public class CVResult: ActionResult
{
    private readonly CV _cv;

    public CVResult(CV cv)
    {
        _cv = cv;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        var filename = "CV - " + _cv.firstname + " " + _cv.name + " - " + _cv.creationdate.ToString("dd MM yyyy") + ".docx";

        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            Inline = false,
            FileName = filename
        };

        using (var doc = DocX.Create(response.OutputStream))
        {
            Paragraph title = doc.InsertParagraph();
            title.Append(_cv.firstname + " " + _cv.name);
            doc.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

and now your action result is no longer cluttered with plumbing code:

```
public ActionResult CVToWord(int id) 
{
    var cv = CVDAO.CV.Single(cv => cv.id == id);
    return new CVResult(cv);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't solve the problem. The files stays empty.

Comment: @Frederiek, I am not familiar with the docx library that you are using. Maybe in addition to calling .Save you need to flush?

Comment: i found the method SaveAs(Stream), but still no help. Going to look for documentation and prey i find what i need.