# save the document created by docX into response and send it to user for downloading

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, docx

I am trying to use the amazing [DocX library on codeplex](http://docx.codeplex.com/) to create a word document.

when the user clicks a button, the document is created and I want to be able to send it to the user immediately via response.. I am doing something similar to this now:

**Edited code based on suggestions**

```
using (DocX Report = DocX.Create(string.Format("Report-{0}.doc", DateTime.Now.Ticks)))
{
    Paragraph p = Report.InsertParagraph();
    p.Append("Title").FontSize(30).Bold()
    .Append("Sub title").FontSize(28)
        .AppendLine()
        .Append(DateTime.Now.Date) 
    ;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Report.SaveAs(ms);


    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".docx\"");
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

    Response.Write(ms);
    Response.End();
}
```

I have tried a few variations of this.. but I am not able to achieve what I want.. [Looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634999/363674) I can possibly save the document on the server and open with io stream.. but I want to avoid that extra step (and then I need to delete the file too)

I don't see the point of creating a file for few milli seconds.. there has to be a way to save the contents and send them to response stream.. right?

How'd I go about it? 
thanks..

EDIT: my current code either throws up cannot open file (Access denied) error If I am using file stream, OR downloads an empty document file without any content (sometimes, type of response is written to document)

---

This code gets me an MS word document with `System.IO.MemoryStream` as it's content..

---

Okay, here is the final working solution:

For some reason, DocX library doesn't want to save to `Response.OutputStream` directly, so I had to save it to memory stream and write the memory stream to response, like [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282740/neil-moss) & [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572644/daniel-hilgarth) suggested. Here's what worked for me:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()
Report.SaveAs(ms);

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".doc\");
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

Comment: I am confused which answer to accept, I could vote both as both helped me...

Comment: Thanks LocustHorde for your question and your final working solution. It does help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`.

Your current code looks really wrong:

You are saving the report to the `OutputStream` of the current response and then **clear that response** (!)

Comment: Hi, my response write is a seperate function that, when I copied into here for simplifying, forgot to re arrange it.. I went on and modified it.. I get permission denied error and I realized I don't wnat file stream anyway, so looking into memory stream now.. thanks

Comment: Hi, is Memory stream safe? does it consume too much of ram if I use it for large files? (files of about 1 MB) ? thanks

Comment: The MemoryStream is virtually simply a byte[] array. So there is no big overhead in using it. You can use it without problems even for big files. BTW: 1MB is not big.

Comment: Hi, doing ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream) worked.. thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: well, 1 MB is not big on it's own, but when it's being used by 30K users per day, it might get a little out of hand!

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late, but I found a way to get this working with FileStreamResult:

```
    public FileStreamResult DownloadDocument()
    {
        using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Test.docx"))
        {
            // Insert a new Paragraphs.
            Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();

            p.Append("I am ").Append("bold").Bold()
            .Append(" and I am ")
            .Append("italic").Italic().Append(".")
            .AppendLine("I am ")
            .Append("Arial Black")
            .Font(new FontFamily("Arial Black"))
            .Append(" and I am not.")
            .AppendLine("I am ")
            .Append("BLUE").Color(Color.Blue)
            .Append(" and I am")
            .Append("Red").Color(Color.Red).Append(".");

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            document.SaveAs(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            var file = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
            {
                FileDownloadName = string.Format("test_{0}.docx", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"))
            };

            return file;

        }
    }
```

The important bit is setting the Position of the memorystream back to 0, otherwise it appeared to be at the end, and the file was returning empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  "ms.Position = 0" did work for me:)

Answer (score 2):

When you do `Report.SaveAs(response.OutputStream);` - it already writes file contents to the output stream. You don't need to do `Response.Write(response.OutputStream);`

So you code should look like this:

```
...

Report.SaveAs(response.OutputStream);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".doc\"");
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got things a little back to front and confused.

First off, clear the output, then add the headers, then write out the content.

```
Response.Clear(); 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".doc\""); 
Response.ContentType = "application/msword"; 

// This writes the document to the output stream.
Report.SaveAs(response.OutputStream); 

Response.End();
```

Also , if your file is a docx format file, append .docx rather than .doc to your filename.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that was my fault, I did not look at the code when I pasted on here to see if it looked alright. I am looking at memory stream now.. thanks

Comment: I don't think you _need_ MemoryStream. The sample above has the Report instance write the document directly to the output stream.

Comment: but that actually wasn't working.. which is why I had to resort to MemoryStream... - using Report.SaveAs(response.OutputStream) gives me an error - method not supported

Comment: None of the code samples in your edits use this sample. The first attempt wrote to the output stream, then cleared the response, and then wrote the headers. The latest edit has you writing to a memory stream, but then you do not copy the content of that stream to the response output stream. 

Have you tried this actual sample?

Comment: Hi Neil, ``report.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream)`` did not work.. however, saving to ``MemoryStream ms`` and doing a ``ms.writeTo(Response.OutputStream)`` worked.. I think it's something to do with the docX library?! thanks your answer + comments pushed me in the right direction

Comment: Ok - good news. Remember to put a `using` clause around your memory stream though!